# Get the number of tiffs in a multi-tiff with command line ImageMagick?

Tags: conversion, tiff, imagemagick

Is there a way to get the number of tiffs in a multi-tiff with a command line utility in ImageMagick?

What I want to to is to extract (split) the multi-tiff into single files. However if the tiff only contains one tiff (is not a multi-tiff), I would like to do nothing at all... Also if I use the "%d"-option to name the output files I get the "%d" in the file name if it is only one.

...or is there another way to use ImageMagick to avoid strange filenames when converting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return the number of pages in a tiff using `identify -format "%p" multipage.tif`.

Comment: Interesting! Tried it and got back: 12345678910111213141516171819202122 if my tiff holds 22 images. Not quite what i expected but will investigate more...

Comment: Hmmm..... I don't have a multipage tiff to try it on.  What version of IM are you using?  On what OS?

Comment: I have tried 32-bit IM version 6.6.1-2 Q8 and Q16 on Windows XP 32-bit and Windows 7 64-bit. I have also tried 64-bit IM 6.6.1-2 on Windows 7 64-bit. All generate the same output with the command you suggested.

Comment: I found the documentation for the strings in the format option (available at imagemagick.org). %p displays pages and %n displays the number of scenes, which is what I was looking for.

The command I will use is then: identify -format "%n" multipage.tif .

Answer (score 8):

Shorter than all of the others:

```
identify multipage.tif | wc -l
```

Comment: Works for me... even when none of the `-format` options produce any output. It should be noted that the reason this works even when `identify` spews lots of error messages (_without_ `|wc -l`), is because errors are written to `stderr`, and `wc` only reads `stdout`

Comment: @Lambart: `wc` reads `stdin`, not `stdout`. It is the pipe that connects `stdout` from the former to `stdin` of the latter. There are other pipes available as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to count the number of pages in a TIFF file:

```
tiffinfo output_file_name.tif | grep "Page Number" | grep -c "P"
```

Comment: `tiffinfo` is a new one to me. Interesting utility, but it isn't able to detect any second image in the tiff I'm working with... also, for a 80MB TIFF, it's generating 345MB of output.

Answer (score 0):

`identify multipage.tif | wc -l`

(-format "%p" or %n produced bogus results for me)

Answer (score 0):

Combined from the answers supplied (using -format and wc to count):

```
identify -format "%p " multipage.tif | wc -w
```

And just to mention ... it's the page numbers we get ( 1 for 1 page, 1 2 for 2 pages, 1 2 3 for 3 pages and 1 2 3 ... 19 20 21 22 for 22 pages)